# format HTML server-side or client-side?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a PHP page that retrieves a list from the DB, and I want to display it on a loaded page using Ajax.

Should I format it on the PHP side (HTML formatting), and just retrieve the data, or pass it to JS like dataA:dataB:dataC and format it client-side?

there won't be a lot of people using it, but I would like to know which is better (if there is a better method without taking the amount of users into account)

Comment: There's not a right or wrong answer here. It depends on many things: server load, data complexity, complexity of target page, size of formatted HTML, and others. For a small system take whichever approach you're more comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Both will work fine. However in my opinion if you're gonna use ajax - and transfer information - a better practice will be to wrap the data in JSON format and parse it on the client's machine.

**Example of the php output:**

```
{
   "row1":{"field1":"value11", "field2":"value12"}
   "row2":{"field2":"value21", "field2":"value22"}
   ...
}
```

**Exmaple of parsing:**

```
$.ajax(...).done(function(result){
    $.each(result, function(index,value){
        $('#conatiner').append('<div>'+index+': field1='+value.field1+', field2='+value.field2+'</div>')
    })
});
```